# Developing an iOS app and an iOS framework in parallel: What's the easiest way to manage the dependency?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on an iOS app which depends on an iOS framework which other devs on my team and I also maintain.

What's the best way to configure my project so that the framework builds as a dependency for the iOS app? My current configuration requires me to build the framework, and then drag it into the XCode project for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it handles frameworks, but I highly recommend using CocoaPods for these kinds of code-sharing projects:

http://cocoapods.org/

Comment: I love cocoapods! One thing I forgot to mention in my original question, is that it's a private framework. Can you configure cocoapods to pull from a local repository?

Comment: I've never set it up myself, but I do use it internally. This seems to walk through the process of setting it up:
http://pablin.org/2013/05/18/cocoapods-for-internal-libraries/